# boost lib, unordered set with c++ is giving me a headache

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-set

ok, I know this is probably going to be something really easy but I have this code implementing the boost libraries (this is my first time using it) and I can't seem to get it to work correctly. here's the code.
hash.h

```
#include .....
#include "boost/unordered_set.hpp"
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

class hash{
public:
    int toHash(string);
    void insertKey(string);
    bool lookupKey(string);
private:
    string hashTable[];
    vector<string> vfile;
    typedef boost::unordered_set<std::string, int> um;
struct hashkey{
    string state;
    int stateno;
};

};

#endif  /* HASH_H */
```

also the hash.cpp

```
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp>
#include "hash.h"

int hash::toHash(string key){
    unsigned int x;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << key;
    ss >> x;
    return x;
}

void hash::insertKey(string key){
    um.insert(key,toHash(key));
}

bool hash::lookupKey(string key){
    return um.find(key)==um.end();
}
```

I'm getting "hash.cpp:18:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token". And I reiterate, I know it's probably quite easy, I just haven't used boost libraries before. I looked at many examples on the internets and I can't seem to just get this "simple" piece to work.Thanks.

Comment: Nitpicking, but your header include guard should wrap the whole file, otherwise you might include the same file multiple times (if it doesn't have proper header include guards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `um` isn't a member variable, it's a typedef.  Get rid of the `typedef` keyword.

Now with regard to your second issue......

Get rid of your hash computation member method & the template's second arg.  Get rid of insert()'s second arg.  boost unordered_set already provides hash functions for many standard types, including std::string.  If you want to hash a user-defined type, though, you will need to provide a hash function, but not in the way you're doing it here.  You'd create an overload of a function named `hash_value()` like this:

```
std::size_t hash_value(yourUserDefinedType_probablyAClassName const &t) 
{
    std::size_t retValue;
    //...compute your hash however you want & store in retValue....
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: nope. if I remove typedef i get:
hash.cpp:18:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char>, int>::insert(std::string&, int)’

Comment: @crazy_pants - OK, that's a separate issue.  I edited my answer to address that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You use typedef to declare a type. um is a type, not a variable. Remove typedef from your code, or declare a variable of type um.

Comment: nope if i say....h

    'code' um um2;

then .cc

   'code' um2.insert(key,toHash(key));

I get a whole mess of errors. like, 'code' hash.cpp:18:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char>, int>::insert(std::string&, int)’
holy jesus why does this not understand code formatting?!?!?!

Comment: @crazy_pants - In comments, put code between backquotes `like this` and it will keep the raw chars you type between them.

Comment: so then again...nope if i say....h `um um2; `then .cc `um2.insert(key,toHash(key));` I get a whole mess of errors. like, `hash.cpp:18:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::unordered::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char>, int>::insert(std::string&, int)`

Comment: The compiler seems to be telling you the trust. `Unordered_set` indeed has no such `insert` method. It wants the value, but not the hash of the value; the set will compute the hash for itself. See [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_set.html#id1683672-bb).